# Using an external CSS stylesheet to style a SVG line

Tags: html, css, xml, svg, line

This is my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns = "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
      xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Red_Circle.xsd">
<head>
<title>SVG Line</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "SVG_Lines.css">
</link>
</head>
<body>
<svg id = "Image_Box">
<line id = "My_Line">
</line>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css document:

```
#Image_Box {
height: 500px;
width: 800px;}
#My_Line {
x1: 100px;
y1: 40px;
x2: 200px;
y2: 90px;
stroke: red;
stroke-width: 3;}
```

When I open my html document in Google Chrome, the line doesn't appear.  I don't know why.  Can you assist me?

Answer (score 1):

`x1, x2, y1, y2` are not CSS elements, but `<line>` element's attributes.

In addition, you should put your `line` tag inside the `svg` tag.

```
<svg id = "Image_Box">
  <line id = "My_Line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" />
</svg>
```